# cumulative addition in numpy

Tags: python, numpy

How to make the loop faster?

```
import numpy as np

# naively small input data
image = np.array( [[2,2],[2,2]] )
polarImage = np.array( [[0,0],[0,0]] )
a = np.array( [[0,0],[0,1]] )
r = np.array( [[0,0],[0,1]] )

# TODO - this loop is too slow
it = np.nditer(image, flags=['multi_index'])
while not it.finished:
  polarImage[ a[it.multi_index],r[it.multi_index] ] += it[0]
  it.iternext()

print polarImage

# this is fast but doesn't cumulate the results!
polarImage = np.array( [[0,0],[0,0]] )
polarImage[a,r]+= image

print polarImage
```

The first print returns:

```
[[6 0]
 [0 2]]
```

The second:

```
[[2 0]
 [0 2]]
```

By the cumulative addition I mean that sometimes two or more values from **image** has to be added together to one cell of **polarImage**

Comment: Please could you turn this into a [MWE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) by giving example inputs? It's not clear to me what your goal is.

Comment: MWE compatible. Please look at it one more time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case the use of `nditer` obscures the process, without improving the speed.  We are more used to seeing a double loop:

```
In [670]: polarImage=np.zeros_like(image)
In [671]: for i in range(2):
    for j in range(2):
        polarImage[a[i,j],r[i,j]] += image[i,j]

In [672]: polarImage
Out[672]: 
array([[6, 0],
       [0, 2]])
```

`polarImage[a,r]+= image` doesn't work because of buffering issues.  The `(0,0)` index pair is used 3 times.  There is a `ufunc` method specifically for this case, `at`.  It performs unbuffered operations; quite possibly using the same `nditer` of your first example, but in compiled code.

```
In [676]: polarImage=np.zeros_like(image)
In [677]: np.add.at(polarImage, (a,r), image)
In [678]: polarImage
Out[678]: 
array([[6, 0],
       [0, 2]])
```

Comment: the np.add.at is what I was looking for. It's 10 times faster!